# The background image style is not applied with setInterval in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, background-image, setinterval

Using AJAX request, I am trying to change background image and set it's style properties. In the function which is called every few seconds through setInterval method, I define style and set states of component in the following way:

```js
changeThings() {
    let maxVal = this.props.data.length;
    let ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxVal));

    let imgVal = (this.props.url[ranNum])? 'url('+ this.props.url[ranNum].url+')':null;
    
    let style = {
      background:imgVal,
      backgroundSize:'cover',
      backgroundPosition:'center',
      bacgkrouhndRepeat:'no-repeate'
    };
    
    this.setState({content:{style:style,
                            section:section,
                            title:title,
                            by:author,
                            dateInfo:updatedDate}});
  }
  
  render()  {
    return ({
      <div>
        //...other components
         (this.state.content.style)? 
          <div id="image" style={this.state.content.style}>:null
        //...other components
      </div>
    })
  }
```

The very first image is displayed with every background image css properties applied. From second images however, it only changes images(background:url value) but not other background image properties such as position, repeat, size etc.

What is the reason of this problems and How can I solve it?

Comment: I dont know whats going on with that render return statement but your ternary is not written correctly. You are also not closing the div tag in your truthy return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the problem. First I only saved URL string data to this.state.content rather than entire css style. It worked when I set the style property directly to the JSX.

Also, basically when DOM define the value for style property of background-size, it calculates the value based on the current 'snapshot' value of element height and width where the image will be display. I am currently making responsive web app so I thought the css style does not work when I changed the view.